# Funny Trig Math Puzzle

Tags: trigonometry

This is a challenging puzzle I heard from my little brother.

For some $n$ and $x$, $\sum_{k=1}^n \sin^{2k}(x) = 2013$.

Is it possible to deduce
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \cos^{2k}(x) \text{ ?}$$

Edit:
I've just noticed something which now seems obvious to me.
Choose $n = 2013$ and $x = \pi/2$ which satisfies the condtion. It follows that the cosine terms would sum to zero. I'm not sure this is a unique solution.

Comment: Check for typos - the index $i$ doesn't seem to appear in the summand, which is usually a bad sign.  Maybe it's supposed to be $\sum_{i=1}^n\sin^{2i}(x)$?

Comment: Oh yes that's what I meant.

Comment: I've just noticed a trivial solution - x = $\pi/2$ and n = 2013. It follows that the cosine sum is 0. Maybe the problem is to show that this is the only solution?

Comment: For a large enough of $n$ there would be an $x$ satisfying the equation, by intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @Maesumi could you elaborate?

Comment: At $x=\pi/2$ the sum is $n$ and at $x=0$ the sum is $0$. The function, ie, the first sum, is a continuous function of $x$, so all values between 0 and $n$ will be be attained. Hence if $n\ge 2013$  then the value $2013$ will be attained. quite possibly multiple times. It looks unlikely that all such $x$'s will yield the same answer in the second sum. How about using $2$ instead of $2013$ and doing numerical experimentation.

Comment: @Mark Let $n \geq 2013$. Let $f(x)=\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \sin^{2i}(x)$.
Since $f(0)=0$ and $f(\frac{\pi}{2})>2013$ by the IVT there exists some $x$ so that $f(x)=2013$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

let $r=sin^2(x)$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n r^k=\frac{r(1-r^n)}{1-r}=2013$$
Now we want:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n (1-r)^k=\frac{(1-r)(1-(1-r)^n)}{r}$$

We can deduce:
$$2013\sum_{k=1}^n (1-r)^k=(1-r^n)(1-(1-r)^n)$$

Comment: So, *if you know $n$*, then you can evaluate the cosine sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I have not tried yet. but the second sum may be simplified and obtained from first one.

Comment: If you know $n$ (and if you can solve a polynomial equation of high degree), yes. If you don't know $n$, I think my answer shows that you can't find the cosine sum just from knowing the sine sum.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: It seems the second sum cannot be written in terms of first sum free from n. And when $n$ is given, one may not need to find an exact solution for $r$ and then put it in second one. for example if one can show the first equation is symmetric around 1/2 he may be able to find the second. However it doesn't seem to be symmetric around 1/2...

Comment: What would be required now is to see for which $0 \le r \le 1$ the first equation has integer solutions for $n$. If there is only one, the answer is affirmative, if there are various pairs $(r, n)$, negative.

Comment: @vonbrand: for sure in if $n<2013$ there's no solution. and for n>=2013 there's at most one solution for $r$.

Comment: @CutieKrait: Why would there be at most one solution? For some n, it seems like there could be at least two solutions for r.

Comment: @Mark: Suppose r and s are two solutions and s<r. Then $$\sum_{k=1}^n{r^k-s^k}=0$$ which is impossible.

Comment: Oh right! So the problem can be solved given an n.

Comment: @Mark: given an n

Answer (score 7):

As noted, the equation holds if $n=2013$ and $x=\pi/2$. Now let $n=2014$. By continuity, there is a value of $x$ a tiny bit smaller than $\pi/2$ for which the equation will hold, and, for this value of $x$, the cosine sum will not be zero. So one cannot deduce the cosine sum from knowing the first equation holds.